# Finding dot product from $|a|, \ |b|, \ |a+b|$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

For vectors $a,b$ we know that $|a|=2$, $|b|=3$ and $|a+b|=4$. I want to find the dot product $a\cdot b$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Should $a$ and $b$ instead be $u$ and $v$ here?

Comment: See [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity).

Comment: @Math1000, why $u$ and $v$ here? Shouldn't there be only $a$ and $b$?

Comment: The title suggests the use of $a$ and $b$, while the question suggests the use of $u$ and $v$. I chose the latter interpretation (since it is ambiguous, after all).

Answer (score 2):

$$|a+b|^2=(a+b)^2=a^2+2\,a\cdot b+b^2=|a|^2+2\,a\cdot b+|b^2|.$$

Comment: The notation is very sloppy here. You mean $(a+b)\cdot (a+b)$ or $\langle a+b, a+b \rangle$ instead of $(a+b)^2$. Anyone having to ask a question about dot products is likely to be confused by using notation that treats vectors as numbers.

Comment: @FlybyNight: nothing sloppy, the variables are vectors (otherwise the question statement would be meaningless) and there is nothing you can misinterpret. $(a+b)^2$ always means $(a+b)(a+b)$ and also $a^2+ab+ba+b^2$ whatever the product that pertains (even valid with matrices).

Comment: Can any of you explain in what way $(a+b)^2$ is ambiguous ?